# Eclipse and Apache Axis2 plugin Java Soap -- Class not found

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, apache-axis

I have eclipse 3.5.1 installed along with the apache axis2 plug in...

I'm trying to generate my web service by going `file -> new-> axis2 service archiver`...
I go through the steps and select the bin directory of my project and when I get to the last step and type in the name of the class and click load it says "`Error: Class not found`"

I have tried about every combination of of paths etc. Not sure what to do next.
Seems like a huge headache trying to build a single soap service... any recommendations...
I was looking forward to only having to write the classes and running that to develop the SOAP service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exact class is missing?

And did you follow a [guide like this one](http://www.bobsindia.com/bobyweb/articles/webservice_axis/)?

Initially I used Axis2 Codegen Wizard and Axis2 Service Archiver. Initially I got few error dialogs like java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

[image] <sup>(not the same error, I know)</sup>

> Though I found out way to fix it by adding few jars to the lib folder of the pluggin and modifying the `pluggin.xml`, it was not really useful as it just generate the required files and there was no possibility I could find to debus the services.

(the rest of the guide describe his development environment)

You also have this Guide in the same idea: "[Writing Apache Axis 2 webservice using Tomcat and eclipse](http://j2eeframeworks.blogspot.com/2007/07/exposing-apache-axis-2-webservice-with.html)"

Comment: The Archiver is going through the steps... When you get to the step were you select a class in your package and then checkbox the methods you want to make public via the web service it can't find the classes in my project. So at the top of the window it just says "Error: Class not found" So for all intensive purposes the archiver isn't failing, it's just like it can't see the public classes in my package..

Comment: The second article is like what I have tried... on the final step before I am stuck it says "Service Name:________" "Class Name:_______" "[] Search Declared Methods only" Here I can't figure out what I need to specify to get it to work...

Comment: The first guide seems to be getting me a lot further... though I am running into this error along the way...                                                                          "Unable to add the follwing facets to project QuickbooksPortal: Axis2 Web Services Core, Axis2 Web Services Extensions."

Comment: @Isisagate: glad you can go on further than before, I haven't played enough with Axis to be of more help on this topic.

Comment: Well looking around seems like I got some issues with the version of Java I am compiling with and the version of java used by tomcat. So overall seems like the first guide is getting me closer. Definitely been one road block after another. Thanks for your help